# How to handle api pagination in karate framework

Tags: api, graphql, response, karate

Suppose, if there are multiple pages and if the user wants to traverse and validate the response in all the pages, then what is the process of validating the same in the karate framework.
Also, if there is any public API available for verifying graphQL in karate

Comment: pagination is nothing special. you may need to loop. for graphql see this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/graphql/graphql.feature